# How to add a trendline to non organized points in Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I would like to fit several points not organized to a trendline in Python,
something like excel does in this image:
[image]

When I try in Python with scipy this is what I got:

```
def fit_ocr2(x,a,b):
    return a*np.log(x)+b
param2, param_cov2 = curve_fit(fit_ocr2, x_ocr, y)
a2 = param2[0]
b2 = param2[1]
test_fit2 = fit_ocr2(x_ocr,a2,b2)

fig0 = plt.figure(0,figsize=(5,10))
plt.plot(x_ocr, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x_ocr, test_fit2, '.-', label='fit2')
plt.legend()
```

What should I do to get the same result in Python (only one trendline)?
[image]

Comment: I think that curve_fit works just fine for fitting. The problem is with your plotting. Try the following: `test_fit2 = fit_ocr2(np.linspace(1,7,100),a2,b2)`, `plt.plot(np.linspace(1,7,100), test_fit2, '.-', label='fit2')`

Comment: @cheetah if I plot with ' * ' works fine, but with line no...

Comment: @JenifferBarreto Try fitting a [second-degree polynomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title suggests you understand what is happening. You are drawing several chords to your curve because the points are not sorted.

As @cheetah mentioned in the comments you could simply use a `linspace` that will give sorted points.

```py
def fit_ocr2(x,a,b):
    return a*np.log(x)+b
param2, param_cov2 = curve_fit(fit_ocr2, x_ocr, y)
a2 = param2[0]
b2 = param2[1]
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_ocr), max(x_ocr), 1000);
y_fit = fit_ocr2(x_fit,*param2)

fig0 = plt.figure(0,figsize=(5,10))
plt.plot(x_ocr, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, '.-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
```

Another option would be to set `x_fit = np.sort(x_ocr)`

Comment: The problem is that my data are not sorted, they are field measurements, I will try to sort them